# Insert columns in a bootstrap tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, multiple-columns

I want to insert 2 columns in a bootstrap tab. The bootstrap code for the tabs is taken from [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/material-design-tab-style). So, how could I put 2 columns in the tab "Home"?

I tried:

```
<div class="tab-content col-sm-6">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col-sm-6" style="width: 200px" id="home">
                Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla Bla bla bla
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Column 2</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- The other tabs (Profile, Messages, Settings) -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide both two columns inside the same `row`

```
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">Column 1</div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">Column 2</div>
       </div>
   </div>

   ... other tabs
 </div
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col tab-content ">HOME </div>
        <div class="col">COLUMN 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Look here : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/